# Exporting 3D objects for people who do not use Mathematica

Tags: graphics3d, export, 3d-printing

I want to export a 3D graphic object plot that I can rotate using the mouse or the trackpad, and send it via email to my collaborators, in such a way that they con rotate it too as they prefer. This would be much better than sending a static image or a video/.gif created by myself, because the collaborators (who do *not* use Mathematica) could explore the graphic details of the 3D object as they want.

Whenever I click on "export model" below the 3D image and choose one of the possible format, I receive a message like the following one:

> Export[$Failed, %19, "X3D"]

> Export::chtype: First argument $Failed is not a valid file specification.

> $Failed

Comment: Maybe other 3D format such  stl, obj,jvx

Comment: There is online version of Mathematica. You can share the link of your code with your collaborators. https://www.open.wolframcloud.com/env/wpl/GetStarted.nb?funnel=WPLExplorations#sidebar=explorations

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci Thank you, I will try.

Comment: @cvgmt thank you, I will try all the formats.

Comment: Actually the error message indicates that the filename is the problem, not the 3d-object or the file-format. The first argument to Export should be a valid file-name, but you provide $Failed. I think you will need to fix that first. Unfortunately we can't help you with that unless you provide the corresponding code...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. (BTW you should share minimal complete code of your example for other's to be able to help you efficiently).

#### 1. Publish in Wolfram Cloud

***Method bottomline**: very simple and fast, does not need any software, works in a web browser even on mobile, but requires internet*

Interactivity you have in Wolfram notebooks, from 3D graphics to `Manipulate` interfaces, etc. can be shared with other via publishing in Wolfram Cloud. Here is a simple example that you can check at **https://wolfr.am/Sig1yEVu** In this way not only your colleagues can get to rotate the cow, but also it is possible to add interactive interfaces.

```
CloudPublish[Manipulate[
Row[{PolyhedronData[g],ExampleData[{"Geometry3D","Cow"}]}],
{g,PolyhedronData[All]}],"TEMP"]
```

[image]

You can also [publish the whole notebook](https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2019/10/the-new-world-of-notebook-publishing). Ultimately you can take advantage of [Wolfram Notebook Embedder](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/WolframNotebookEmbedder/) and use it on personal websites (like for instance Wolfram Community is already doing, see many posts in http://wolfr.am/StaffPicks ). Make sure you understand [Wolfram Cloud Credits](https://www.wolfram.com/cloud-credits/) system. Also check [PermissionsGroup](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PermissionsGroup.html) and [CloudDeploy](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CloudDeploy.html) for flexible options on sharing permissions and access.

#### 2. Free Wolfram Player

***Method bottomline**: high level of interactivity, iOS compatible, no need for internet, but requires FREE software installation.*

If your colleagues are OK to install FREE Wolfram Player, which is very simple too, then your problem is solved by simply sending them the notebook. They will not be able to evaluate the code, but all interactivity will be available to them. The notebook will even open and work on a mobile iOS device, which I use a lot btw when for example someone sends me an email with a notebook and I am traveling.

- https://www.wolfram.com/player
- https://www.wolfram.com/player-app
- https://apps.apple.com/us/app/wolfram-player/id1059014516

#### 3. Export 3D object to external service or format

Study docs around function [Printout3D](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Printout3D.html) and related functions [HERE](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/3DPrinting.html). It can help you to use external service or file format (like .STL) to share 3D-interactive objects, for example:

```
Printout3D[ExampleData[{"Geometry3D","Beethoven"}],"IMaterialise"]
```

which you can check out here: https://bit.ly/388bpIs

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot! Such a great and complete answer!! By the way, I would like to point out that I did not put any code in this question because I collaborate with a hedge fund, which prevents me completely from public anything "too specific."  This also means for me to consider that I should avoid any *other* person access my code, i.e., there is also a very important privacy issue.

Comment: @PenelopeBenenati Thank you :-) I am very glad it helped. Also check PermissionsGroup and CloudDeploy for flexible options on sharing permissions and access via Cloud. Also if you do not want to expose some code, you can try to make up some toy fake example that reproduces the issue, that's usually what I do. Good luck and happy new year :-)

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions @VitaliyKaurov ! Happy New Year to you too! :-)

Answer (score 1):

also check this:

https://jerryi.github.io/wljs-docs/blog/intro-transform-3d/

the source code:

https://github.com/JerryI/Mathematica-ThreeJS-graphics-engine

It can support a subset of 3d plot

pros: easy to share, since it's just js.

cons: not **so** functional